# Best way to convert numeric variable to ordered factor

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(n = 100, mean=0, sd=1),
                  Edu=sample(x = c(-999,12,13,14,16,1), size = 100, 
                             replace = T, prob = c(0.05,0.2,.2,0.2,0.2,0.15)))
```

I want to convert the variable `Edu` to an ordered factor variable. I can convert it to a character variable with this code:

```
lutedu <- c('-999' = NA, '12' = "High School", '13' = "Associate's", 
         '14' = "Associate's", '16' = "Bachelor's", 
         '18' = "Master's, Graduate/professional", '21' = "PhD")

df1$Edu <- lutedu[as.character(df1$Edu)]
```

and from there I could convert the character variable to an ordered factor with `ordered()`:

```
df1$Edu <-
  ordered(
    x = df1$Edu, levels = c(
      "High School", "Associate's", "Bachelor's",
      "Master's, Graduate/professional", "PhD"
    )
  )
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `as.factor` does not work?

Comment: yes, in fact i mentioned it in my question. Is that the best way?

Comment: I think it is, I can't imagine other ways to do that. Let's wait other users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of recoding with a named vector and then calling `ordered`, you can save yourself a step by calling `ordered` and using both the `levels` and the `labels` arguments:

```
ordered(edu, levels=c(-999, 12, 13, 14, 16, 1),
        labels=c("NA", "High School", "Associate's", "Bachelor's",
                 "Master's/Graduate", "PhD"))
#   [1] High School       Master's/Graduate Master's/Graduate Bachelor's        Associate's      
#   [6] Master's/Graduate High School       Master's/Graduate High School       PhD              
# ...
```

**Data**:

```
set.seed(144)
edu <- sample(x = c(-999,12,13,14,16,1), size = 100, 
              replace = T, prob = c(0.05,0.2,.2,0.2,0.2,0.15))
```